# why am I getting charged for app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am getting charged for App engine also even though I am using only compute engine.

I have attached snapshot of billing info bellow:

Billing snapshot:

[image: Billing snapshot]

Please tell me how to disable the billing for App engine because this is the highest charge.

Edit 1:

Below is the new bill after app engine is disabled you can see I am charged for app engine even I disabled it. And charged for cloud SQL even if I have deleted the instance.

[image: bill after disable]

Comment: Did you check **all** the items on the bill? They're all credited, your total is 0...

Answer (score 1):

From the console you should be able to navigate: `Hamburger (upper left) -> App Engine -> Settings -> Disable Application`. This will disable billing and usage of App Engine.

Comment: I have disabled it. event though getting charged. I had created an instance of google cloud SQL. I have deleted that also but still getting charged

Comment: You'll be charged for any service that has been enabled and used. You can't retroactively not be charged.

Comment: You can contact Google Cloud billing support if you need more information on your charges. You can fill [this form](https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/cloud_platform_billing) to get in touch with them.

Comment: I have the similar issue. please help me there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74496090/deleted-cloud-sql-instance-and-still-get-charged